# HTML parsing sorting

Tags: python, html, parsing

So I have an HTML file that contains one large table. As you can see below, the first row of the data contains headers and the rest of the rows are the information for a movie.

```
          <tr class="row0">
            <td class="column0 style0 s">show_id</td>
            <td class="column1 style0 s">type</td>
            <td class="column2 style0 s">title</td>
            <td class="column3 style0 s">director</td>
            <td class="column4 style0 s">cast</td>
            <td class="column5 style0 s">country</td>
            <td class="column6 style0 s">date_added</td>
            <td class="column7 style0 s">release_year</td>
            <td class="column8 style0 s">rating</td>
            <td class="column9 style0 s">duration</td>
            <td class="column10 style0 s">listed_in</td>
            <td class="column11 style0 s">description</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="row1">
            <td class="column0 style0 n">81145628</td>
            <td class="column1 style0 s">Movie</td>
            <td class="column2 style0 s">Norm of the North: King Sized Adventure</td>
            <td class="column3 style0 s">Richard Finn, Tim Maltby</td>
            <td class="column4 style0 s">Alan Marriott, Andrew Toth, Brian Dobson, Cole Howard, Jennifer Cameron, Jonathan Holmes, Lee Tockar, Lisa Durupt, Maya Kay, Michael Dobson</td>
            <td class="column5 style0 s">United States, India, South Korea, China</td>
            <td class="column6 style0 s">September 9, 2019</td>
            <td class="column7 style0 n">2019</td>
            <td class="column8 style0 s">TV-PG</td>
            <td class="column9 style0 s">90 min</td>
            <td class="column10 style0 s">Children &amp; Family Movies, Comedies</td>
            <td class="column11 style0 s">Before planning an awesome wedding for his grandfather, a polar bear king must take back a stolen artifact from an evil archaeologist first.</td>
#... continue to row100
```

I'm trying to develop a function that returns either a list of lists or a list of dictionaries to answer some questions about the data. I am aware of the get_text() function for getting the text, but unsure how to really implement the rest. I am very new to python so any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Can you upload that file and share the link: I'd like to help you but I need the full code.

Comment: yeah this is the url that I download https://raw.githubusercontent.com/msyamkumar/cs220-projects/master/spring20/final/netflix_titles.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

with open("nf_shows.html", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    html = f.read()

soup = bs(html, "html5lib")
table  = soup.find("tbody").find_all("tr")
headers = [x.text.strip() for x in table[0].find_all("td")]

tv_shows = []
for tv_show in table[1:]:
    vals = [x.text.strip() for x in tv_show.find_all("td")]
    tv_dict = dict(zip(headers, vals))
    tv_shows.append(tv_dict)
```

---

```
{'show_id': '81145628', 'type': 'Movie', 'title': 'Norm of the North: King Sized Adventure', 'director': 'Richard Finn, Tim Maltby', 'cast': 'Alan Marriott, Andrew Toth, Brian Dobson, Cole Howard, Jennifer Cameron, Jonathan Holmes, Lee Tockar, Lisa Durupt, Maya Kay, Michael Dobson', 'country': 'United States, India, South Korea, China', 'date_added': 'September 9, 2019', 'release_year': '2019', 'rating': 'TV-PG', 'duration': '90 min', 'listed_in': 'Children & Family Movies, Comedies', 'description': 'Before planning an awesome wedding for his grandfather, a polar bear king must take back a stolen artifact from an evil archaeologist first.'},
...
```

---

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/723681cae2)